# Believe/believing me right now

Tags: difference

> Why are you not believing me right now?

Vs

> Why don't you believe me right now?

What is the difference? Which one sounds more natural in terms of its usage and what meaning do they carry?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you tell Tom that you were in a meeting when he called and that's why you missed his call but Tom seems to not buy it. Then you say to him

> "Why are you not believing me right now? "

you are focusing on Tom's action at that particular moment. You may trust that Tom generally believes you but right now you doubt that he is believing you.

I doubt that using "Why don't you believe me right now?" would be grammatically wrong though.